# How typed data on query in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, types

Using codeignite framework, PHP and mysql when I do a query all data retreived are typed as String. Maybe muy tables have got strings, integers... Bit if I return a JSON of the query rows, al values are String. Well, I can cast any value that I considerate that is a int, boolean, ... but this is a boilerplate conde that I want forget.

Is there any way to query data and receive the real type¿

Comment: might be related http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317938/3859027 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430657/3859027

Comment: No magic solution, it's a mysql limitation. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2430640/3778613) . Maybe `field_data()` will help you [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/fields.html)

Comment: I believe that the key is use PDO, no?